# tikzpicture - Align stacked barplot to y-axis with ymin=0

Tags: latex, tikz

I am trying to make a stacked barplot aligned to the y-axis of the tikzpicture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    ymin=29,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Seconds (s)},
    symbolic x coords={t1, t2, t3, t4},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 143) (t2, 203) (t3, 174) (t4, 188)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 34) (t2, 36) (t3, 39) (t4, 35)};
  \legend{\strut S1,\strut  S2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As seen, I have used ymin to force it being close to the y-axis but it does not look perfect. Also, I want to be able to automate this since I have a lot of figures that needs this configuration and doing it manually takes time.

Comment: There is one thing which confuses me about this question: if you want to align the barplots to the y axis at zero, why are you setting `ymin` to 29 and not to 0?

Comment: Then they will just float, like this: https://i.imgur.com/xvahvkl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ymin=0` and without additional enlarging of this limit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    ymin=0,
    nodes near coords,
%    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Seconds (s)},
    symbolic x coords={t1, t2, t3, t4},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 143) (t2, 203) (t3, 174) (t4, 188)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 34) (t2, 36) (t3, 39) (t4, 35)};
  \legend{\strut S1,\strut  S2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```